# Is this Erza's new armor in the new chapter of the Fairy Tail manga?

Tags: fairy-tail

I just checked out the new chapter of the Fairy Tail manga. In page 10 of chapter 372, after Erza was freed from the dungeon by Natsu, when that demon bird woman came back to check up on her, Erza shows up in front of her, and equips this new armor that I never seen before in the anime.

[image]

Did Erza just unlock a brand new suit of magic armor on page 10 in fairy tail chapter 372?

Comment: Welcome to the Anime and Manga StackExchange! I've edited what I could of your post for grammar - if I've changed the meaning of something feel free to edit that back in.

Comment: I added a picture, please remove it if I got the wrong one

Answer (score 1):

Erza uses [Requip:The Knight](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/The_Knight) armor as mentioned [here](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_372) in the magic used section. This type of armor has various type. So this particular one used by erza might be another variant of it which was not mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It is called the Piercing Armor. It allows her to pierce through substances and leave an hole within them. That was actually the first time she used it within manga/anima.

Comment: Can you cite where you get the name from?